# Critical values of analytic functions of several variables

Tags: analytic-functions, critical-point-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be real analytic. Define $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d, \nabla f (x)=0\} $. Is it true that for any compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $f(S\cap K)$ is a finite set ?

Comment: I am probably missing something, but could the downvoters explain their vote? The answer doesn't seem trivial to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can assume that $K$ is a cube, by enlarging it. Then $S \cap K$ is a bounded definable set in the $o$-minimal structure $\mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{an}}$ (obtained by adding restricted analytic function, cf [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118545?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)).

By the Yomdin-Gromov parametrization lemma, there exists a finite family $(\phi_i : ]0,1[^{d_i} \rightarrow S \cap K)_{i \in I}$ of differentiable functions whose images cover $S \cap K$.

For each $i$, the function $f \circ \phi_i$ is differentiable with vanishing differential, so that $f \circ \phi_i = c_i$ for some constant $c_i$.
Thus $f(S \cap K) \subseteq \{ c_i  \ | \ i \in I \}$ is a finite set.

EDIT: I just realized one could avoid the use of the Yomdin-Gromov parametrization lemma. Namely, $f(S \cap K)$ is a definable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ wrt the aforementioned o-minimal structure. It is therefore a finite union of points and intervals. Since it has zero Lebesgue measure by Morse-Sard's theorem, it must consist of finitely many points.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just need to see the definition of $o-$minimal structure because I am not familiar with this notion. Do you think the result would extend to the case of a function piecewise analytic (i.e defined on $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is a (semi-)analytic surface ? )

Comment: It works for any $C^1$ function which is definable in some $o$-minimal structure. It is not the case e.g. for $x \mapsto \sin(1 / x)$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: So I need to check that a piecewise analytic function is definable in some o-minimal structure. I am not familiar with the usual proofs, would you recommand a reference ? Thanks

Comment: A standard reference is https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/tame-topology-and-o-minimal-structures/7AC940248AF2B05DA4D33E4FB05C97A2. Francois Loeser, who has a few papers in the field, gave a course on o-minimal theory a few years ago in Paris 6, and notes were taken (in french), which can serve as a gentler introduction (sect. 2-5): https://www.eleves.ens.fr/home/guignard/pdf/ominimal.pdf.

Comment: I read the references but I still don't know if the result still holds for functions $f $ that are real analytic on some bounded connected open set. In the references you mentioned, the analytic functions are restricted to a cube.

Comment: It is ok if the bounded open is itself definable (for example with piecewise real-analytic boundary). The restriction of $f$ to a cube containing the open is definable, hence its restriction to the open subset is definable as well.

Comment: The image of a definable function of a definable set is itself definable. But in my case (real analytic function), does it mean that in order to apply your result, the function has to be real analytic on a cube that contain the open set ? The function I study is just defined on the open set and I don't know if can be extended to a analytic function on a cube.

Comment: Ah, je vois. Non, on a besoin que la fonction s'etendent a un ouvert plus grand, contenant l'adherence du premier ouvert (pas forcement un cube).

Comment: Donc en toute généralité c'est vraisemblablement faux. En revanche, cela doit être juste dans mon cas car il me semble que le graphe de la fonction $f:Ω⊂ℝ^d→ℝ$ que je regarde est précisément une surface semi-analytique dans $ℝ^{d+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For another approach, see "Morse-Sard theorem for real-analytic functions" by Jiří Souček and Vladimír Souček. (Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae, Vol. 13 (1972), No. 1, 45--51)